# Detect cells in NSTableView that become invisible after scrolling

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview, nstableviewcell

I want to detect when cells in `NSTableView` become invisible when the user scrolls. In iOS, the UITableView has a delegate method with signature `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath`, but I could not find anything simular in the delegate methods of NSTableView.

Comment: There's `tableView:didRemoveRowView:forRow:` but what do you mean by "removed", become invisible or views removed from the table view?

Comment: @Willeke I have changed the question to prevent confusion with 'removing' cells, which is something different (related to removing data).

Comment: You'll probably need to get notified when the scroll view scrolls/moves (search for answers, there are lots of ways to get this notification), then get the `visibleRect` of the table view. That will tell you the bounds of what's visible; cells outside are not.